# Do subspaces of a vector space contain additive inverses of its elements?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, set-theory

In the textbook 'Linear Algebra Done Right' by 'Sheldon Axler', the requirements for a subspace are listed as

- contains the additive identity
- is closed under addition
- is closed under scalar multiplication

There is no requirement for containing additive inverses.

So if subspaces are vector spaces themselves, shouldn't containing additive inverses also be a requirement??

Comment: It is redundant, closed under scalar multiplication means $-1 \cdot v \in V$ for any $v \in V$.

Comment: @JairTaylor That's a solution. Could you please put it in the solutions section?

Comment: @rschwieb Sure.

Comment: Note also that the axiom "contains the additive identity" is *almost* redundant. If $V$ is a vector space, and $W$ is a non-empty subset of $V$ that is closed under addition and scalar multiplication, then it follows that $W$ contains the additive identity. The only reason that this axiom is not entirely redundant is because it prevents the empty set from being a subspace of $V$.

Comment: You have the right viewpoint for sure. In general, the definition of a sub-(anything) should be a subset that’s also an (anything), and that has shares the same special constants. Then your list of criteria should be seen as a proposition giving a slightly simpler characterisation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no need for a separate axiom for the existence of additive inverses, since closure under scalar multiplication means $-1 \cdot v$ for any $v \in V$ and $-1 \cdot v$ is an additive inverse of $v$: $$-1 \cdot v + v = -1 \cdot v + 1 \cdot v = (-1 + 1) \cdot v = 0 \cdot v = 0.$$